# Get Zoo Visitor members based on category?

Tags: categories, channel-entries

Is there a way to get Zoo Visitor members based on their category?

I don't see a category filter option in the `{exp:zoo_visitor:memberlist}` - tag.
Only a membergroup filter option.

Or should I take another approach?

I also tried working with the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="zoo_visitor" category_group="2" category="14" dynamic="no"}  
    {title}  
    {exp:zoo_visitor:details}  
        {visitor:member_firstname} {visitor:member_lastname}  
    {/exp:zoo_visitor:details}  
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But nothing gets returned.

Answer (score 2):

There is a global variable for the categories associated with the currently logged in member. Not quite what you're looking for by the sounds of it though,, but it depends on what you're looking to use the category for:

```
{visitor:global:categories_piped}
```

Hope that helps a little.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of any other post have you though about using the categories tag pair within the channel:entries tag?

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/channel/channel_entries.html#id154

Perhaps you could then filter the categories tag on 'show_group=' and/or 'show='